# play-framework : can't call view (function) in another view (@content not found)

Tags: function, templates, view, playframework

I have problems calling a view into another view ... It seems I can't understant how things work ...
So I have this view (`NewArea.scala.html`):

```
@(content: Html)(k:String)
@Main("Add new Area") {    

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    ....
 <li><a href="@routes.Application.newarea(k)">New Area </a></li>
    ...
</nav>

<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">    
    @content
</div>

}
```

> rout:

```
GET     /newarea                controllers.Application.newarea(id:String)
```

> controller:

```
 public static Result newarea(String id){
        return ok(newarea.render(id));
    }
```

And the `@content` , i want to be this view (`newarea.scala.html`):

```
@(k:String)

@NewArea("") {

<form action="@routes.Application.PostNewArea(k)" method="POST">

   Area name :  <input name="name">     
   <input type="submit">

</form>
}
```

I get this error :

> not found: value content
> **@(content: Html)(k:String)**

The Main (`Main.scala.html`) template looks like this, if it helps:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain, on this example, how to do things right, please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@(content: Html)(k:String)
```

to

```
@(k:String)(content: Html)
```

In `NewArea.scala.html`

Scala template is like a fuctions.When you define `NewArea.scala.html` you say
`NewArea` takes parameter of type Html,String but when you are calling it you are passing String,Html the order is not same so it gives an error.

[Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates#Template-parameters)